# .show and .animate at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, jquery-animate, nav

I have a nav which you can see here: http://hutchcreative.co.uk/rod/. If you click on the menu icon and then contact you can see the icon changes to a X. I would like to add an animation on this, instead of using .hide() and .show(). However whenever I have added .animate it doesn't seem to apply.   Does this mean I cannot replace .show() with .animate? Do i have to combine the 2 somehow?

I have posted my jquery below:

```
$('#menuIcon').toggle(function(){
   $('#navigationWrapper ul').show();
   $("#navigationWrapper").addClass('activenav');
 },
 function(){
   $('#navigationWrapper ul').hide();
    $("#navigationWrapper").removeClass('activenav whiteSection');
});


$('#navigationWrapper #menu-item-59').click(function(){
    if($("#navigationWrapper").hasClass('whiteSection')){
        $('#contactWrapper').slideUp("slow");
        $("#navigationWrapper").removeClass('whiteSection').addClass('activenav');
        $('#menuIcon').animate({
        opacity: "show"
        }, {
        duration: "slow",
        easing: "easein"
        });
        $('#closeIcon').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#contactWrapper').slideDown("slow");
        $("#navigationWrapper, #navBlog").addClass('whiteSection');
        $('#menuIcon').hide();
        $('#closeIcon').animate({
        opacity: "show"
        }, {
        duration: "slow",
        easing: "easein"
        });
    }
});

$("#closeIcon").click(function () {
    $('#contactWrapper').slideUp("slow");
    $('#menuIcon').animate({
    opacity: "show"
    }, {
    duration: "slow",
    easing: "easein"
    });
    $('#closeIcon').hide();
    $("#navigationWrapper, #navBlog ").removeClass('whiteSection').addClass('activenav');
});


$('#navBlog #menu-item-59').click(function(){
    if($("#navBlog").hasClass('whiteSection')){
        $('#contactWrapper').slideUp("slow");
        $("#navBlog").removeClass('whiteSection').addClass('activenav');
        $('#menuIcon').animate({
        opacity: "show"
        }, {
        duration: "slow",
        easing: "easein"
        });
        $('#closeIcon').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#contactWrapper').slideDown("slow");
        $("#navBlog").addClass('whiteSection');
        $('#menuIcon').hide();
        $('#closeIcon').animate({
        opacity: "show"
        }, {
        duration: "slow",
        easing: "easein"
        });
    }
});
```

The look im trying to achieve is when you click on contact the menu icon slides up and the X slides up from the bottom, so it looks like it is pushing it out of the way basically.

Comment: Take a look at this question on hide and animate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931101/css-animate-fadeout-and-position/

Comment: I think my code is very similar to this, but im not sure why it isn't working though. I have updated it with the animation im trying to use on .show()

Comment: I think if you want people to help you debug this wall of code, the least you can do is to put together a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You want your click event to trigger the animations for your close button and menu button simultaneously.  Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/84skB/1/).

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:black;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#header{
    text-align:right;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    padding:5px;
    height:60px;
}

.pink{
    background-color:#ffaaaa !important;   
}

#menu, #buttons{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
}
#menu{
    width:100%;
}
#menu ul{
    margin:0 60px 0 0;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
    line-height:60px;
}

#menu li, #buttons li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#menu{
    float:left;
}

#buttons li
{
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
}

#buttons a{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    line-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
}

#closeButton{
    background-color:blue !important;
}

#contactInfo{
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    padding:40px;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#menuButton").click(function(){
    $("#menu").toggle("slide"
                      , {direction: "right"}
                      , 1000
                      , function(){
                          $("#header").toggleClass("pink", 1000); 
                      });
});

$("#contact").click(function(){
    $("#menuButton").toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
    $("#closeButton").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
    $("#contactInfo").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
})

$("#closeButton").click(function(){
    $("#menuButton").toggle("slide", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
    $("#closeButton").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
    $("#contactInfo").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="stuff">stuff</a></li>
            <li><a id="moreStuff">more stuff</a></li>
            <li><a id="contact" href="#">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <ul id="buttons">
        <li><a id="menuButton" href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a id="closeButton" href="#" style="display:none;">Close</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="contactInfo" style="display:none;">Some Contact information goes here.</div>
```